# jQuery date-picker not showing the first Saturday of every month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jQuery date-picker in my entire application but in two places the date-picker is not showing the first Saturday of every month.

[image: Date-picker snap]

As you can see in this snap its not showing the 3 Sept as its a Saturday.
Here is my code.

```
 $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});
```

jQuery librarys

```
<script src="${request.getContextPath()}/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="${request.getContextPath()}/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: inspect the element and look at the applied css rules.

Comment: in inspect it showing date 3 but here its not showing.

Comment: why its not showing? is the color white or display is none?

Comment: @Ryan I can't reproduce it... I make and example and its working properly. Can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exAMc/1/), it may help you

Comment: I don't think its a css problem but i sure the color is not white because everywhere its working but here its not working.